# Error installing iPython on mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, ipython

When I try to install iPython on my mac (using terminal), I get following error. I am running OS X Yosemite.
PIP version: `9.0.1`
Python version: `2.7.8`

```
$ pip install ipython

   Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 412, in run_egg_info
    self.setup_py, self.name,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 387, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I have also tried `pip install ipython[all]` or `sudo pip install ipython` or `pip install ipython[all]`.
Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem with mine a bit back. I resorted to installing the conda environment, which has a GREAT gui for mac and it includes iPython (now jupyter) notebooks and the iPython console and Spyder IDE as well. It is not the easiest way, but I find using conda commands to maintain and install is more reliable on my mac.

Comment: @bethanyP - thanks!! 
Installed Anaconda from https://www.continuum.io/downloads. After installation confirmed iPython is installed from terminal `$ conda list ipython`

Comment: you are very welcome!